# Could not set background color of Tab.Navigator of @react-navigation/bottom-tabs' version 6

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I could not found an API of Bottom Tabs Navigator v6 (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs) that allows me to change the backgroundColor of the container that wraps my TabBar. For example, in the below picture I would like to change the backgroundColor from white to black

[image]